# Help interpreting car window wiring diagram

Tags: wiring, diagram

I would be grateful if anyone can help interpret the attached wiring diagram for my 2003 Toyota Camry power windows.

The switch for my driver side window is busted so it is currently stuck at down.

I want to attempt to jump the connectors to get the window up again.

Can anyone point out the main pin connections for the power, ground and up and down positions (i.e front right window)?

[image]

Comment: 2 wire or 5 wirte motor?

Comment: Unfortunately, while the diagram clearly shows the switch connections for both rear and left hand side front window, it only shows a single connector going from the "Power window master switch" to the "Right hand front window motor", with no further information about how the switches are connected to this connector. Perhaps these details are on a different page ?

Comment: I think all the details are on that page, except perhaps the shape of the connector at the motor end of the wire.  being in the same door as the window the motor connects to the controls via the large D shaped plug,

Answer (score 1):

Its the red and green wires that go to the motor

well "R" and "G" which I'm guessing translates to red and green.

It looks like 12V on "G" and ground on "R" will make the motor go up.

Comment: I believe the OP is asking about the right hand front window (RHF, probably a left hand side drive country.)  The diagram only shows a single connector for that window with no further information.

Comment: that seems like enough to me all the other windows use variations of green and red and connect 12V to green to raise the window.

Comment: But it shows the RHF motor being connected straight to the control unit ("power window master switch" - we dont know what that is, could be a PCB). Would you risk backfeeding anything into it ? One could unplug that connector and then connect the motor straight to power to roll the window back up, but if the down switch is stuck it would roll down again as soon as the plug is reconnected.

Comment: @Unimportant the 5 pin window motor assembly (one pin isn't used) has rotary sensors for auto up and auto down and collision detection. They can be ignored, typically you can wire a 2 pin motor assembly without issue (or feature of course). The master switch is a semi complicated pcb. With microcontrollers and relays even.